# Azure AD Authentication alongwith Passport Authentication

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, authentication, iis

I am working on a legacy application (WebForms), succesfully switching to Azure AD Authentication using the v2.0 endpoint.

The issue is that some users have Windows live ID which uses passport authentication. And they can't register to the site now.

Customers will probably raise hell for this, is there any solution to incorporating those users as well?

e.g. yahoo email id should also be able to authenticate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the description,  you were migrating the app with Azure AD authentication. Based on my understanding, the Azure AD V2.0 endpoint support both the Microsoft Account( Windows Live Id) and origination Account. If the customer have the Microsoft Account( Windows Live Id), they can login-in your app without require registering to the site.

> e.g. yahoo email id should also be able to authenticate.

If you also want your app to support login-in with the Yahoo account, you need to complete the login business logic yourself. For example, as far as I know, Yahoo also support OpenId connect protocol, more detail about developing with Yahoo, you may refer [here](https://ms.portal.azure.com/?flight=1#resource/subscriptions/ed0caab7-c6d4-45e9-9289-c7e5997c9241/resourceGroups/ResourceGroupFei/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/webhooksFei/authv2).

In addition, the scenario you were describing is more like support the app login-in with the social account. In this scenario,  [Azure AD B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/) tenant is more suitable however it currently only support Facebook, Google+, LinkedIn, and Amazon. But the Micrsoft will add support for other popular social identity providers based on customer demand. You can submit the feedback from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) if you were interesting using Azure AD B2C tenant